# Horizontal scrolling site responsive?

Tags: responsive-design, horizontal-scrolling

I've searched the internet for an answer to making a horizontal scrolling site (ie:  http://nquinones.4ormat.com/fashion-1 ) responsive with no success.

HTML:

```
<div id="horizontal">
    <div class="picture">
        <img src="pic01.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="picture">
        <img src="pic02.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="picture">
        <img src="pic03.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#horizontal {
    width: 2000px;
}

.picture {
    float: left;
}

img {
     height: auto;
     max-width: 100%;
}
```

I'm really lost on this. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You might want to define what you mean when you say "horizontal scrolling responsive"? Does it mean you get a scroll bar if the row of pictures is wider than the screen?

Comment: Something like this: http://nquinones.4ormat.com/fashion-1

Comment: I don't know what I'd call that. When scrolled all the way left, the first image is offset enough that the left margin text all shows. As the images are scrolled horizontally, they take up the whole width with the left margin area appearing to be a translucent pane through which the left side of the image area can be seen, though obscured. Very cool effect.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just put a solid white image on the left, before all the other images. Make it just wide enough so that when the images are completely unscrolled, the white part goes behind the left nav portion.

```
<div id="horizontal">
    <div class="picture">
        <img src="allwhitebox.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="picture">
        <img src="pic01.jpg" />
    </div>
```

You do the translucent thing with opacity

```
#left-margin {
    opacity:0.4;
    filter:alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

Something in the back of my head says you will need:

```
.picture {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just google for "Metro UI Template" & download it from the first result shown...

**Study it & go experimenting....**